# Get the row and column position of a ordered 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am working on a project in Java where I need to order a 2D array according to their values in non-decreasing order and find the position (row and column) after ordering their elements. I will try to explain this with an example.

Let us consider as an example an array of 4x4 (obviously the numbers of rows and columns may vary):

```
array = [[2,0,36,90],[128,39,168,159],[44,9,105,193],[150,245,256,305]]
```

I had transformed this array in a vector of 16 (4x4) elements where each element is ordered in non-decreasing order:

```
ordered_vector = [0,2,9,36,39,44,90,105,128,150,159,168,193,245,256,305]
```

Now that I need is to build an *ordered_array* where each element represents the row and column position of the elements of "array" ordered in non-decreasing order. For example, the first position of *ordered_vector* is 0 that corresponds to row 0 column 1 in array; the second position of *ordered_vector* is 2 that corresponds to row 0 column 0 in array; the third position of *ordered_vector* is 9 that corresponds to row 2 column 1 in array; and so on.

The complete output must be the following:

```
ordered_array = {{0,1},{0,0},{2,1},{0,2},{1,1},{2,0},{0,3},{2,2},
                 {1,0},{3,0},{1,3},{1,2},{2,3},{3,1},{3,2},{3,3}};
```

Would be highly appreciated if I can get some help with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check if this code work for you?

CustomArrayElement.java

```java
public class CustomArrayElement {
    int element;
    int row;
    int column;

    public CustomArrayElement(int element, int row, int column) {
        this.element = element;
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "{" + this.row + "," + this.column + "}";
    }
}
```

SortByElement.java

```java
import java.util.Comparator;

public class SortByElement implements Comparator<CustomArrayElement> {
    @Override
    public int compare(CustomArrayElement o1, CustomArrayElement o2) {
        return o1.element - o2.element;
    }
}
```

OrderArrayClient.java

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class OrderArrayClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int array[][] = {{2, 0, 36, 90}, {128, 39, 105, 159},
                {44, 9, 105, 193}, {150, 245, 256, 305}};
        int row = array.length;
        int column = array[0].length;
        CustomArrayElement customArrayElement = null;
        List<CustomArrayElement> listElements =
                new ArrayList<CustomArrayElement>(row * column);
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                customArrayElement =
                        new CustomArrayElement(array[i][j], i, j);
                listElements.add(customArrayElement);
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(listElements, new SortByElement());
        int[][] output = new int[listElements.size()][2];
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listElements.size(); i++) {
            if (i % 2 <= 1) {
                output[i][j] = listElements.get(i).row;
                output[i][j + 1] = listElements.get(i).column;
                j = 0;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
                if (k == 0) {
                    System.out.print("{" + output[i][k] + ",");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(output[i][k] + "}");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{0,1}
{0,0}
{2,1}
{0,2}
{1,1}
{2,0}
{0,3}
{1,2}
{2,2}
{1,0}
{3,0}
{1,3}
{2,3}
{3,1}
{3,2}
{3,3}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first prepare a sequence of pairs of 2d array indexes and then sort that sequence by the corresponding array values using the
[`comparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction)) method:

```java
int[][] arr = {
        {2, 0, 36, 90},
        {128, 39, 168, 159},
        {44, 9, 105, 193},
        {150, 245, 256, 305}};
```

```java
int[][] arr2 = IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
        .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, arr[i].length)
                // pair of 2d array indexes
                .mapToObj(j -> new int[]{i, j})
                .toArray(int[][]::new))
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        // sort by the corresponding array values
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(pair -> arr[pair[0]][pair[1]]))
        .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

```java
// output
Arrays.stream(arr2).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

```
[0, 1]
[0, 0]
[2, 1]
[0, 2]
[1, 1]
[2, 0]
[0, 3]
[2, 2]
[1, 0]
[3, 0]
[1, 3]
[1, 2]
[2, 3]
[3, 1]
[3, 2]
[3, 3]
```